# How to programmatically set radiobutton and select option with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

For ex. we have

```
<select id="menu">
<option value="1">sample 1</option>
<option value="2">sample 2</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<input type="radio" id="parentcheck" value="1">Button 1 
<input type="radio" id="parentcheck" value="2">Button 2
```

I want to simply "clone" user input. Let's say we want to set them to exact values and trigger their functions.

---

In my case i have functions for both of them

```
 $("#menu").change(function () {...
 $(".parentcheck").click(function () {...
```

For ex. how to select Sample 1 and Button 1 and fire their function?

Comment: comment from @f0x originally via the answers: "you have two element with the same `id`, that's invalid and could be replaced by a classname"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first case you can use `.val()` and trigger the event *manually* in both cases.

**Consider the following**

```
$('#menu').val(2).trigger('change');
```

In the above, we select the option with the value of 2.

**And for the radio buttons**

```
$('#parentcheck').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Note that unlike the OP's code, each radio button must have a unique ID that is referenced here

Answer (score 2):

Just set the attribute of the option/checkbox

For the options it is "selected" and for the checkboxes it is "checked"

Also, trigger the event after that using trigger()

Example:

```
$( '#menu option[value=whatever]' ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' ).trigger( 'change' );
$( '.parentcheck' ).attr( 'checked', 'checked' ).trigger( 'click' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something you are looking for...

```
$("#menu option[value='1]").attr("selected",true).trigger("change");
$("input[type='radio'][value='1']").attr("checked",true).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Again the same answer

```
$("#menu option[value='1]").prop("selected",true).trigger("change");
```

`$("input[type='radio'][value='1']").prop("checked",true).trigger("change");`

use .prop instead of .attr